# Javascript, String operation, Regex or something else

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am the worst guy on regular expression and any string operation in JavaScript/jquery, can you please help with some stuff ?

http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4040/5160997583_5ea677e4e1_s.jpg

this is an URL structure example in need to get from this url  **5160997583**

Thanks for helping !

Comment: You'll need to explain yourself a bit more: do you want to find the first 10 characters of the file name? Do you want to find all characters of the file name up to an underscore? Do you want to find the starting digits of the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the structure is always the same and that you want to find all characters of the file name up to the first occurrence of an underscore, you can just do:

```
var str = "http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4040/5160997583_5ea677e4e1_s.jpg";
var num = str.split("/");
num = num[num.length - 1].split("_")[0];
alert(num);
```

`str.split("/")[-1]` gets `5160997583_5ea677e4e1_s.jpg` and then we split that string on `_` and grab the first part of that string.

Alternately, you could do:

```
var num = str.replace(/\/(\d+)_[^\/]+$/i, "$1");
```

Comment: You can't have negative array indexes in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`var code = url.match(/\/([0-9]+)_[^\/]*$/)[1];`

(EDITED to be more restrictive)

Comment: You regex has the chance to match before reaching the file part. For example in `http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4040_/5160997583_5ea677e4e1_s.jpg` it will match `4040`.

Comment: That is true. For the answer to be perfect the question would have to specify the exact possible syntax of the url.

Answer (score 0):

A regex that will find the starting digits of the file name would be this one

```
/\/(\d+)[^\/]+$/
```

and you use it like this

```
url = "http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4040/5160997583_5ea677e4e1_s.jpg";
matches = url.match(/\/(\d+)[^\/]+$/);
alert(matches[1]); // here it is /
```